# Download .plist from server and save it locally in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, save, plist

I want to integrate in-app purchases into my application, and so I'd like to download .plist files whenever users buy new level sets. How can I download a file from a server and save it so that it stays in my iPhone app forever ?

**EDIT**

I want to achieve something like that:

- As there are not many of these plists (never more than 20) I could just include them into the app and set a boolean value with `isPurchased` or so, right ?
  If the user purchased the category, the boolean is set to `YES`.
  Whenever new categories are added by me, I'll just have a whole new update like "Cut the rope" for instance do it. Is that a good approach ?

Comment: Look at NSURLConnection Class to see how to load URL request to download data, then NSFileManager to save the downloaded data to disk (Documents directory of your app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Why don't you use [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) services for In-App purchases? Why using your very own implementation? I am not sure but...do you think you will get Apple's approval? As far as I remember, Amazon did something similar in the past and they *didn't* get it.

Second: I wouldn't use NSData for this purpose. If you have a valid property list, then it is the best solution to use

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"foobar.com/plistfile.plist"]];
```

You could then store this dictionary. To be honest, I wouldn't recommend using your solution. If I understood you correctly, you would have thousands of plists after some time. My suggestion: Use a "global" mutable dictionary as ivar of your App Delegate for example. This should be empty at the beginning. Then download your helper dictionaries as mentioned above and populate your global dictionary with

```
[[delegateInstance globalDictionary] addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
```

each time you get new data.

Save it with

```
[[delegateInstance globalDictionary] writeToFile:@"path" atomically:YES];
```

and recover it each time your app starts up.

**EDIT:**

Of course you can do it that way. If these plists really store information, that's fine. For example you could store billing information there, so that they are not interchangeable for other users (or shouldn't be at least). BUT: If you only want to get information about the question if a users bought a specific level or not consider combining your information within one plist (as described above). Anyway: Consider a possibility for your users to get back their data. Think of somebody deleting your app accidentally. How do you want to explain to him all his purchases are lost? In-App purchases are safer.

Or at least: Store a copy of the receipts on your server and let the users login to gather what they paid for in the past ;-)

Have fun and good luck! :-)

Comment: By the way: To address the issue that was already mentioned (request might block) you should use asynchronous loading. If you don't know how to do this, there is a fantastic wrapper called ASIHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty one-liner:

```
[[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://<yourfile>.plist"] writeToFile:@"pathforthefile.plist" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Very dirty; `dataWithContentsOfURL:` blocks, which means network problems could cause the app to freeze up. It's not ideal for anything other than local URLs.

Comment: So you want to repeatedly download the same file from the web, but give it a new unique name each time locally?

Comment: If locking up the app is the only thing you're worried about, dispatch it on a background thread. or perform the selector in background, just sayin.

Comment: Do you simply want to persist the name of the plist file as it exists on the server?

Comment: You can simply wrap this in a GCD dispatch block to avoid freezing the main thread.